# MYSQL - Retrieve the amount using the IN clause

Tags: mysql, sql, join

So, I'm working on a blog platform which has posts and comments. Today, to show the amount of comments of each post I run a query, so the bigger the number of posts, the bigger the number of queries (and database connections). I would like to know if it's possible to retrieve this information in one query only. For example, a single query to return:

```
Post 1 => 5 comments
Post 2 => 10 comments
Post 3 => 0 comments
```

Something like this, if I can explain myself lol

```
SELECT amountOfComments FROM comments WHERE post_id IN ('1', '2', '3');
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for a simple aggregate query. You can query table `comments`, and group by `post_id` to count how many records exist for each post:

```
SELECT post_id, COUNT(*) amountOfComments 
FROM comments 
WHERE post_id IN (1, 2, 3) 
GROUP BY post_id
```

Comment: I'm gonna give it a try

Answer (score 0):

You want counts of zero, so you need to generate the rows that you want.  In MySQL, you can do:

```
select p.post_id, count(c.post_id) as num_comments
from (select 1 as post_id union all
      select 2 as post_id union all
      select 3 as post_id
     ) p left join
     comments c
     on c.post_id = p.post_id
group by p.post_id;
```

Presumably, you have an actual `posts` table, in which case this should also work:

```
select p.post_id, count(c.post_id) as num_comments
from posts p left join
     comments c
     on c.post_id = p.post_id
where p.post_id in (1, 2, 3)
group by p.post_id;
```